# pretty_compile in pyethereum

Tags: pyethereum, python

I am learning Serpent with pyethereum in Spyder (so I have a running log of what I have tried and learned), but I am stuck in translating standard features of Serpent (such as `pretty_compile`) from python.

For example, how do I `pretty_compile` the standard multiply by 2 contract?

```
import serpent
from ethereum import tester, utils, abi

# Initialize tester blockchain
s = tester.state()

serpent_code = '''
def double(x):
    return(x*2)
'''

c = s.abi_contract(serpent_code) # Usual compiling
```

Is there a `pretty_compile` argument of `abi_contract`, or perhaps of `print`? I would very much like to see the opcodes for more complicated contracts within pyethereum.

Comment: Have you tried `c = s.abi_contract(serpent_code, pretty_compile)`? It looks like `abi_contract` should take general keyword arguments (I think).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried both your suggestion, and `c = s.abi_contract(serpent_code, 'pretty_compile')` but no luck. Part of the challenge is that I cannot find documentation about the arguments of `abi_contract`, except for the 2s preview Spyder gives me before I close the brackets.

Comment: You've imported `tester`, which contains the definition, here: https://github.com/ethereum/pyethereum/blob/9cd646f304384aa71102894fb14cbbc9771e26a7/ethereum/tester.py#L208. I was looking at the `kwargs` argument, but it looks like that doesn't help.